# How to change the initial view controller of storyboard?

Tags: ios

I have 2 view controller ,and I disabled the initial view controller of first view controller ,and enabled the second view controller,but when start the project,the initial view controller is still the first view controller ,what should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tap the second view controller, and select `"Is initial View Controller"` in `Attributes inspector`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks,I have enabled this,but didn't solve the problem... Is there any wrong in Xcode?

Comment: any chance you set your root controller using first controller storyboard id like [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstController"]

Comment: This option works. If you have "Embed In" Navigation Controller, in your ViewController, then you have to use this option at the Embedded Navigation Controller instead of ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do this with code too.
In your `AppDelegate` class's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method you can write

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let secondVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
self.window?.rootViewController = secondVC
```

**Edit 
 Swift 3.0**

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let secondVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
self.window?.rootViewController = secondVC
```

Assuming that your storyboard name is `Main.Storyboard` and your SecondViewController **Storyboard ID** and **Restoration ID** is also set in Identity Inspector and use Storyboard ID is checked.

[image]

Comment: How did you managed? With code or some other approach. If my answer helped you, kindly tick as accepted

Comment: Your answer has helped me.I'm sorry, I forgot to tick.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starter like me ( both iOS and OSX mechine ) and you wanted to change the  entry point within same storyboard, then,

-> long press on the entry point arrow.
-> drag it to the view controller you wish to make the starting point, the arrow will now move to your new screen.