# Application starting in webview xcode 9

Tags: swift, xcode9

Pretty new to swift & xcode 9. I have my webview code working and displaying the proper link, but it opens the app with it. I have a few different controllers before it should be displayed (ultimately button triggered). When I have this code in, it doesn't change the default view controller as link, it simply loads the webview right away. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // 1
    let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))

    // 2
    let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))
    toolbarItems = [refresh]
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    title = webView.title
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Probably you want to modify `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate` class when you create the first _UIViewController_. Or maybe the _Storyboard enter controller_ if you use Storyboard. Can you post AppDelegate's code?

Comment: @lubilis the appdelegate code is too long. Is there a specific part i can post?

Comment: Yes, the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

Comment: import UIKit
    import WebKit

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
     launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

Comment: Ok, Is your app opening the webview or you only see the launchscreen?

Comment: @lubilis opening directly into the webview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the initial view controller of storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677127/how-to-change-the-initial-view-controller-of-storyboard)

Comment: That doesn't seem to apply. I have 3 view controllers before the button is presented to start the stream which then moves to another view controller with the web view. Having the code in doesn't change the initial view controller, just loads the webview right away.